# Connection timeout because of proxy server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, web-services

I am trying to consume an `API` in eclipse. When I am in `VPN` it goes for `connection timeout`. As soon as I disconnect `vpn` it gives proper output. Can anybody guide me how can I resolve the issue? what modification is needed in below code.

```
package com.shruti.getapi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class NetClientGet {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Inside the main function");
             URL url=new URL("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
             HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
             conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
             if(conn.getResponseCode()!=200)   //Here it goes for connection timeout in VPN
             {
                 System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
                 throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error Code: "+conn.getResponseCode());
             }
             InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
             BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(in);
             String output;
             while((output=br.readLine())!=null)
             {
                 System.out.println(output);
             }
             conn.disconnect();
             
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you cannot do anything but increase the timeout of the rev-proxy.

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass proxy server ?

Comment: If you know address of the machine(s) it is delegating to and it is accessible, sure. But usually there is a reason for having a rev-proxy and getting getting around it can lead to unexpected behaviour. Cannot reccomend that.

Comment: thanks @BenjaminEckardt .Actually increasing timeout time is not helping. connection timeout error is coming after the time i specified. Is there any other way to handle that?

Comment: Can you determine the exact source of the timeout? What is causing it?

Comment: It is not able to reach to API  server because of proxy server.

Comment: Increasing the timeout on the proxy does not fix your issue?

Comment: No. It does not resolve. If I put 5 min then connection timeout error comes after 5 min

Comment: Is it possible that VPN connection slows you down that much, that it is actually correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout of the [connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout-int-).

```
conn.setConnectTimeout(0); // infinite timeout
conn.setReadTimeout(0);    // infinite timeout
```